# html file page not showing in wordpress webpage?

Tags: wordpress

If i add the following tag in wordpress page,

```
<iframe src="file:///var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/themes/codium-dn/fund.html" name="frame1" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="no" scrolling="auto" align="center">
</iframe>
```

it doesnt show that html file in wordpress webpage,

can anyone help me solve this. Is there any way to do it

Also help me if is there any way to convert that html file into shortcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be working, refer below link,

http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/wordpress/wordpress-introduction/adding-html-wordpress

Answer (score 0):

It should be working.

But, you have to put this code in the plain text or html, not in the default text editor wordpress uses.

It is located in the right upper corner of the text field when you are editing this page.

See the image below

[image: screenshot]

Comment: yes I put that iframe tag exactly in that text and I am not using any plugins

Comment: There is a plugin I think that helps wordpress users to add iframes. Somethin like: https://el.wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-iframe/